# Comparing values in columns and returning boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have four columns with column names(ma5,ma10,ma20,ma60). I would like to see if in each row, it satisfies: ma60>ma20>ma10>ma5(numbers in these columns in this specific row), return 1 if true and 0 if false. so I tried the following:

```
(eachstockdf['ma5']>eachstockdf['ma10'] and 
eachstockdf['ma10']>eachstockdf['ma20'] and 
eachstockdf['ma20']>eachstockdf['ma60']) *1
```

I want it return a series with 0 and 1 as indication of whether the condition is met. but it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know it works when I compare only two rows. For example:

```
((eachstockdf['ma5']>eachstockdf['ma10'])) *1
```

but how can I do this to compare four columns? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bitwise `&` operators, pandas overloads those.

Also, each condition must be wrapped in another set of enclosing parens, because of the precedence of bitwise operators.

```
( (eachstockdf['ma5']  > eachstockdf['ma10']) & 
  (eachstockdf['ma10'] > eachstockdf['ma20']) & 
  (eachstockdf['ma20'] > eachstockdf['ma60'])  ) * 1
```

As a note, you could also convert `bool` to `int` with

```
(....).astype(int)
```

Comment: sure. thanks, I am going to do it after 7 minutes because i dont know why somehow the system won't let me do it now..

Comment: @SongWu Ah, sure. No problem,.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe consists only of the four columns `ma5`, `ma10`, `ma20`, and `ma60` (or any arbitrary order of consecutive moving averages), then one could compare the values of each column to check if they are greater than (`gt`) the shifted values of the column to the left (`axis=1` for rows).  The first column of such a comparison would always be irrelevant as there is nothing to its left, so exclude it via `iloc[:, 1:]`, and then check if all row values are true to ensure the MA of each row is monotonically increasing.

You can convert the boolean values to indicators of `1`/`0` simply by adding zero to the result (`.add(0)`) which coerces the result to integers.  Alternatively, you can use `.astype(int)`.

Note that this method is much more general than using named columns for comparison, as it allows an arbitrary number of consecutive moving averages with arbitrary windows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['ma5', 'ma10', 'ma20', 'ma60'])

df.gt(df.shift(axis=1), axis=1).iloc[:, 1:].all(axis=1).add(0)
```